# Getting error while buying test ether from https://faucet.metamask.io/

Tags: metamask, ropsten, mastering-ethereum

I just tried to buy a test ether from https://faucet.metamask.io but the faucet address which is supposed to give 1 ether doesn't have enough balance.

[Snapshot of the faucet address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L575.png)

And when i click on the button "request 1 ether from faucet" i get this this error:

> {"error":"[ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload
>   {\"id\":7622897729724,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"params\":[{\"to\":\"0xb4b199e03506d505278aa0636790fcddaeb0afd3\",\"from\":\"0x81b7e08f65bdf5648606c89998a9cc8164397647\",\"value\":\"0xde0b6b3a7640000\",\"data\":\"0x\"}],\"method\":\"eth_sendTransaction\"}
>   [object Object]"}

I am using Ethereum wallet **MetaMask** chrome extension and I am connected to **Ropsten test network**. I am following the instructions from the book **Mastering Ethereum: Building Smart Contracts and DApps** book by Andreas Antonopoulos and Gavin Wood.

Your help will be appreciated.

PS: Please bear any mistakes because this is my first post and I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Try https://faucet.ropsten.be/.

Comment: Currently, https://faucet.metamask.io/ has a balance of 0.5 ether. It happens quite frequently... if you need your test ether fast, just post your address in response

Comment: Thank you @goodvibration got 1 ether by your method.

Comment: 0xB4b199E03506D505278aA0636790FcDDAEB0aFd3

Comment: @m1k3y3 above is my address. need 1 ether.

Comment: you should already have it...

Comment: Thank you @m1k3y3 got your ether. Thank you guys as beginner your response is really helpful.

Comment: @m1k3y3 pardon me. I meant to write need 1 more ether.